# Assigning multi-line raw string to variable for use in read_csv

Tags: python

I am trying to assign a raw file path to a variable for use in read_csv in python. The ultimate intent is to take file path as an input in a GUI, and use this to run read_csv. The string is very long, and, for the time being, I am just trying to get the string - variable assignment working.

I followed another thread which suggested using r'''drive:\yada\yada...''' however this adds an additional "\" to each step in the file path. Any suggestions for how to prevent this? Also, any suggestions on best approach to take a file path as input to a GUI and use this to read_csv would be greatly appreciated.

Example of problem below...

```
In[219]: pathProject = r'''C:\Users\Account\OneDrive\
\Documents\Projects\2016\Shared\
\Project-1\Administrative\Phase-1\
\Final'''

In[220]: pathProject
Out[220]: 'C:\\Users\\Account\\OneDrive\\\n\\Documents\\Projects\\2016\\Shared\\\n\\Project-1\\Administrative\\Phase-1\\\n\\Final'
```

Comment: what you are seeing is just a representation of the string ([__repr__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)). The string itself contains characters that cannot be printed (like the newline character `\n`) so the representation you see is with special characters escaped. Try calling `print(pathProject)`.

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) has a decent article explaining string escaping. You should always be aware that what you're looking at might just be a representation (not exact) of what the variable is.

Comment: Excellent thanks ... that worked! There was another issue in my code messing up the read_csv filepath... which I was incorrectly attributing to this representation difference

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter a long string by spliting it on many lines, you can take advantage of Python's string concatenation. As you want to enter it on many lines, they have to be included in parentheses, for example:

```
pathProject = (r"C:\Users\Account\OneDrive"
    r"\Documents\Projects\2016\Shared"
    r"\Project-1\Administrative\Phase-1"
    r"\Final")

print(pathProject)
# C:\Users\Account\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\2016\Shared\Project-1\Administrative\Phase-1\Final
```

Note the opening and closing parentheses, and that each part of the string has to be declared as a raw string.